# How to say that something happened in the past while emphasizing that it is not finished yet?

Tags: tenses, emphasis, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

Let's say that we are in a 2-round tech-competition for which we have already entered the selected list of the first round and waiting to see the results for the 2nd round. Here I want to put the emphasis on the fact that our work was good enough to have the above result.

I want to somehow put that in my resume as one sentence for the sake of brevity!

If I say "Our solution has already shortlisted us in the X competition", would that send the message that we are waiting for the final evaluation? or maybe people misunderstand that's the best we could have made for this competition.

What if I say "Our solution currently shortlisted us in the X competition"? is it grammatically correct and also does it better emphasize that we are waiting for the rest of the evaluation?

Comment: Why not “advanced us to the final round in the competition”?  To me short-listed is a phrase from another kind of competition, e.g. books. But perhaps it applies here—there is a panel of judges?

Comment: And is your title missing a word?

Comment: @Xanne: I already came up with this: "So fat, our solution has shortlisted us in the X competition."

Comment: Your _solution_ has not shortlisted you, that has been done by the judges. Your solution can be said to have _enabled_ you to be shortlisted: it can have _led to your being_ shortlisted: it can even _have been_ shortlisted in its own right but it has _not_ shortlisted _you_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest “*Our solution qualified us for the second round.*”

> Qualify = to succeed in getting into a competition:
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/qualify)